# How to automatically generate pre-filled links of google forms

Tags: javascript, automation, google-api, google-forms

I hope you're doing well.

I want to share a google form with some friends to fill their personal preferences for a trip. 
I have some people's information on excel but not all of them. 
So I found that it is possible to send personalized pre-filled form URLs to your recipients, but it is very manual : https://support.yet-another-mail-merge.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004266085-Send-personalized-pre-filled-form-URLs-to-your-recipients

Do you know an easy way to automate the generation of pre-filled forms to my friends ?

Answer (score 0):

Generate the manual URL once with obvious place holder data.
Then create an excel file with all the data you want to pre-fill.
Use an excel formula to create the URLs. Copy the column with the formulas and paste as values. The links are now unique to the data in their row.

Use an ampersands to concatenate the data, quotes “around text” and use the substitute function to encode special characters to HTML, Below the cell containing first entry is A2.
You can nest substitutions like so SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","%20"),"'","%27") to handle data with spaces and, in this case, apostrophes.
[Click here to see how that would look in MS Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrS3d.png)

Comment: I think there are better places to ask such questions in the StackExchange network, such as [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).